# TS2322: Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement'. and other errors when enabling button on pressing terms checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button, null

I would like to enable/ disable a button when someone presses the terms checkbox and I created the following function:

```
const enableButton = (checkBox: HTMLInputElement ) => {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_button");
    var isChecked = checkBox.checked;

    if(isChecked) {
        submitButton!.disabled == false;
    } else {
        submitButton!.disabled == true;
    }
}
```

I am doing it with React and TypeScript. When I change it to the following, I get the error that you can see in the description. In general I think I am missing something with assigning types etc. Whatever I do, when I fix something I get different errors.

```
var submitButton: HTMLButtonElement = document.getElementById("submit_button");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Document.getElementById(elementId: string): HTMLElement | null` by the default returns `HTMLElement | null`

`HTMLButtonElement` is more specific type.

Since, `getElementById` just can't know what type of element are you looking for it just returns more general type.

In order to handle this, you should create your [custom typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). Since somebody always can change your HTML.

```js
import React from 'react'

const hasProperty = <
  Obj,
  Prop extends string
>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);


const isButton = (element: HTMLElement | null):
  element is HTMLButtonElement =>
  Boolean(element) && hasProperty(element, 'disbaled')

const enableButton = (checkBox: HTMLInputElement) => {
  var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_button");
  var isChecked = checkBox.checked;

  if (isButton(submitButton)) {
    if (isChecked) {
      // don't need to use exclamation mark
      submitButton.disabled == false;
    } else {
      submitButton.disabled == true;
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3gAsUaAFHMJWATzgF44AeUnDgB5AEYArADRC4rCGDhIAHjCRUAJjTh0owKgHNSAPgAUESQC5RkqXDBtr8sAEpZ1ixLjBt4rwDJEJEooDX5nOwBXKgBrKggAdypjXmNZP2CYADoHCBg8znYsxhoRJOcOGE4stBQAGzrzW3s2FwBucgpqOm8aACFImHyqXjhTJDqkEHUYawAJABUAWQAZAFFJ6ap4AB84KkiGl0tZCamZ3rhF1YGh6g3z7dTZPogISZQqcc2Zlzh-QIlCpcb6PGB2fAaHxiepIDT4NxdWjwdQoMSTW7DUamND0YIxV7KebLFYASSoYEGDy2MD%20PBSAG9ZAA3FBQHSRMQgYAwTHUUYaCBoSI0rIGJAwakzPqcUkaUwAIhonO5MAA%20mJBsMFe0WWzegBhPFoGJw0a4-GEmrG00aDqyYCYMY%20PlfZVcnmulx-JnCYSO500I34uE%202R%20uAAekjcEFVHw8CoSDN%20TgkRoSCUyjQdRQIBQMGA-PzUBi4b97tVrqyUJoaMmGl4fEw9QzHQjAF8lHUM3BfRGOR7eVrqDWfPWzTw%20DAoJEkO2-R3ZEuO0A)

Comment: Your type guard is a little bizarre... it's much easier and more correct to just check `(element instanceof HTMLButtonElement)`

Comment: Ahaaa thanks! In case I now want to use this as a function inside the checkbox input, it doesnt really work. I have the following:<ChBox
                    onChange={( ) => {enableButton(this)}}
                    name="term"
                    id="term"
                .................. It complains that this is undefined

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer please update your question with this example

Comment: @Mack I just don't trust `instanceof` operator. I prefer to use `hasProperty`.

Comment: Your method is not reliable... There are elements other than buttons that have a `disabled` prop. I believe your distrust is misplaced.